# Finding the best approach to "Add a recipe module to Magento"

Tags: php, api

**What is the best approach to add a recipe module to Magento.**

The thing I would like to avoid is to add database-tables to Magento core which later it might cause problems.

There should be relationships between grocery products on Magento and the recipes.

- The user chooses the recipe and should be able to add the products of the recipe to the cart by one click.

Is API approach a good solution? 
Please share your thoughts I appreciate it.

Example:
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.marked.no%2Fmat%2Fbarnas-p%25C3%25B8lsefavoritt

Comment: Have you considered grouped products?

Comment: @adjco

I'm totally new into Magento, if you please share more details or links and examples, it would be alot of help.

Answer (score 0):

I would install and modify a blog extention i.e. awblog, for recipes.

You could add a custom field in admin to store skus then in phtml file that renders your post modify accordingly to show those products.